# what are the units in joint_limits.yaml?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
In joint_limits.yaml, there are two kinds of limits which are max_velocity and max_acceleration.
I wonder what are the units of those limits?
max_velocity : m/s or rpm ?
max_acceleration : m/s2 or rpm/s?
I will be grateful if  any of you could help!
Thank you!

Gu Tianqi!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243105/what-are-the-units-in-joint_limits.yaml?/) by [gutianqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26191/gutianqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'm assuming this is `joint_limits.yaml` found in the `config` sub dir of MoveIt configuration packages)

Just as everything else in ROS (or more precisely: just as everything in ROS *should*), the `joint_limits.yaml` file follows the rules described in [REP-103: Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

For angles, that would be *radians*, for lengths, *metres*.

So:

- revolute joints:

  - position: radians
  - velocity: radians/sec
  - acceleration: radians/sec^2
  - jerk: radians/sec^3
- prismatic (or linear) joints:

  - position: metres
  - velocity: metres/sec
  - acceleration: metres/sec^2
  - jerk: metres/sec^3

See also:

- [What are the units and coordinate conventions in ROS?](http://answers.ros.org/question/9065)
- [wiki/ROS/Patterns/Conventions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Patterns/Conventions)
- [wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4